# How to prevent caching in Ember Data

Tags: caching, ember.js, ember-data

I have been using Ember/Ember Data for over 5 months now and the one thing that has caused me the biggest grief is the fact that Ember Data caches everything. There is no way to prevent it. I do know that there are methods like model.reload() and that anything with query params retrieves uncached but oftentimes I find myself needed to manually unload records from the data store.

It is common for data to be modified by a user other than the user of the app. Without the help of web sockets to always keep Ember Data in-sync, there needs to be an easy way to load data from a server with an updated copy. Again, without a web socket, it is not possible for the client to know that the unerlying data changed.

If there are other model frameworks that can be used in Ember to help with this issue, I'd be interested in those as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

although, I don't recommend this at all, I see the caching as the best part \end rant.  You could create a self unloading model (just realize as you unload, associated records will see that record as gone).

```
App.UnloadingModel = DS.Model.extend({
   unloadTimespan: undefined,
   _scheduledUnload: false,
   _unloadWatcher: function(){
     var time = Em.get(this.constructor,'unloadTimespan'),
         loaded = this.get('isLoaded'),
         scheduledUnload = this.get('_scheduledUnload');

     if(!scheduledUnload && time && loaded){
       this.set('_scheduledUnload', true);
       Em.run.later(this, this.unloadRecord, time);
     }
   }.observes('isLoaded').on('init')
});

App.Color = App.UnloadingModel.extend({
    color: DS.attr()
});


App.Color.reopenClass({
    unloadTimespan: 4000
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/70/edit